# DB2 iseries materialized view refresh

Tags: db2, db2-400

I have created the following materialized query table:

```
CREATE TABLE SCHEMA.TABLE AS
  (SELECT * FROM SCHEMA.TABLEEXAMPLE)
     DATA INITIALLY DEFERRED
     REFRESH DEFERRED
     MAINTAINED BY USER
     DISABLE QUERY OPTIMIZATION;
```

When I execute a `REFRESH TABLE SCHEMA.TABLE` it get locked for others users to read from it.

Reading this doc from IBM https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000977.html

I tried to execute this statement:

```
REFRESH TABLE SCHEMA.TABLE ALLOW READ ACCESS
```

But I get the following error: `SQL State: 42601 Unexpected keyword ALLOW`

What I'm missing on statement? Is there other way to allow read access to materialized query table while it is beign updated?

Comment: Do not reference a Linux/Unix/Windows page for Db2-server, if the Db2-server runs on i-Series.   Different operating system, different Db2 flavour.  The correct page for i-series Refresh Table is https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzhrefresh.htm   and as you see it does not support that clause.  It may be possible to specify a lesser isolation clause on the SELECT for the mqt.

Comment: Thanks mao. Did you know how to specify isolation level? I have tried with WITH UR option at the end of select statement:

SELECT * FROM SCHEMA.TABLE WITH UR

But I get error SQL State: 57033, file is in use

Comment: Consider searching the Db2 for i knowledge center for `isolation level`

Answer (score 1):

MQTs on Db2 for IBM i lag behind the functionality available in Db2 for LUW.

I've never bother with them, instead an encoded vector index (EVI) with computed columns meets every need I've every considered.  (Note that Db2 LUW doesn't have EVIs)

Per Mao's comment, you might try deleting an recreating the MQT with the following:

```
CREATE TABLE SCHEMA.TABLE AS
  (SELECT * FROM SCHEMA.TABLEEXAMPLE)
     DATA INITIALLY DEFERRED
     REFRESH DEFERRED
     MAINTAINED BY USER
     DISABLE QUERY OPTIMIZATION
     with NC;
```

But I think a refresh would still require exclusive access to the MQT.

The only options I can think of for "refreshing" an MQT while it is being used

- programmatically , using either triggers on the base tables or perhaps a process that uses SQL to update a few rows at a time.
- removing the `DISABLE QUERY OPTIMIZATION` and not accessing the MQT directly.  Instead depend on the optimizer to access it when appropriate. Now you can create a version of it every few hours and the Db should start using the newer version for new queries.  Once the older one is no longer being used, you delete it (or `REFRESH` it)